# layout:row missing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

can anyone help with missing layouts? 
I used ImageView , however I can't find field `layout:row` and also `layout:columns` in the Text or in the properties. [missing layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHDGL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltIRa.png)

Comment: Your ImageView is outside gridlayout, modify code and place </GridLayout> after ImageView

Comment: please post your logcat error and relevant xml layout

Comment: @shahzainali How do you come to know OP has used GridLayout? and that also code is written outside?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya he has attached image of code and now it is removed, check it https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv1Ia.png

Comment: thank you for answering. yes the problem is that i cant drag the image on top of my grid layout

Comment: I uploaded the print screen

Comment: now it works, i needed to drag the image to the component tree and not to the design screen itself. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There should be two tabs under the Design window, one labeled "Design" and another labeled "Text". In the text tab, you can edit the raw layout xml, i.e. by moving the ImageView's tag(s) to between the `<GridLayout .... /></GridLayout>` tags. This approach is, incidentally, applicable to most instances of the Design editor refusing to take your orders.